# How do I get the cgroup path for a podman container?

Tags: cgroups, container, podman

Is there a way to get the cgroup root path(s) for a podman container?

It seems `podman inspect` does not reveal anything about cgroups.

One "hacky" way I've found is to do something like

```bash
# Run the container, writing its container ID to /tmp/cid
podman run --rm -it --cidfile=/tmp/cid busybox

# Search /sys/fs/cgroup for the CID
cid=$(cat /tmp/cid)
find /sys/fs/cgroup | grep "/libpod-$cid/" | grep '/cpu,cpuacct/' | grep '/cpuacct.usage'
# prints something like: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/libpod_parent/libpod-abc123.../cpuacct.usage
```

But I am not happy with this solution, because:

- It requires an inefficient search (`find`)
- I'm not sure whether the search path of `/sys/fs/cgroup` is guaranteed to be correct
- If cgroup v2 is in use, the file I am looking for might have a different basename (for example, it might be `memory.current` instead of `memory.usage_in_bytes` for cgroup v2)

Is there a more direct way using podman or perhaps one of the Go SDKs to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to know is the container ID. There's no need to use `find` or `grep`; you can construct the explicit path for what you want just by insert the container id in the right place.

With `cgroupsv2`, the base path is `/sys/fs/cgroup/machine.slice/libpod-<container_id>.scope`. Under that directory, you'll find:

```
cgroup...
container...
cpu...
cpuset...
hugetlb...
io...
memory...
pids...
```

With `cgroupvs1`, the path is `/sys/fs/cgroup/<cgroup>/machine.slice/libpod-<container_id>.scope`. So if you want the `cpu,cpuacct` cgroup, you ask for:

```
$ ls /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/machine.slice/libpod-756bf46cd9ff1f509f65d063b69e42a5a560b9d29608ec48ec7466880b26d65e.scope
cgroup.clone_children
cgroup.procs
cpu.cfs_period_us
cpu.cfs_quota_us
cpu.rt_period_us
cpu.rt_runtime_us
cpu.shares
cpu.stat
cpuacct.stat
cpuacct.usage
cpuacct.usage_all
cpuacct.usage_percpu
cpuacct.usage_percpu_sys
cpuacct.usage_percpu_user
cpuacct.usage_sys
cpuacct.usage_user
notify_on_release
tasks
```

Comment: if it is rootless the folder is not correct

Comment: That's true, but a simple `find /sys/fs/cgroup |grep <pod id>` will help you find it. With cgroups v2, that will be `/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-<UID>.slice/user@<UID>.service/user.slice/libpod-<PODID>`